# How to crawl an entire website with Scrapy?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm unable to crawl a whole website, Scrapy just crawls at the surface, I want to crawl deeper. Been googling for the last 5-6 hours and no help. My code below:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "example.com"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/"]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), 
                  follow=True),
             Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=()), callback='parse_item')
    ]
    def parse_item(self,response):
        self.log('A response from %s just arrived!' % response.url)
```

Comment: Just tried your code against stackoverflow - my ip got banned. It definitely works! :)

Comment: @Alexander - Sounds encouraging for me to debug more :) :) ... Sorry on the IP ban mate !

Comment: Are you really trying to crawl example.com?  You know that's not a real website.

Comment: Which website are you trying to crawl?

Comment: "example.com" was used for representative purposes only. I'm trying to crawl landmarkshops.com

Answer (score 6):

Rules short-circuit, meaning that the first rule a link satisfies will be the rule that gets applied, your second Rule (with callback) will not be called.

Change your rules to this:

```
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
```

Comment: @All - Got it working ... Steven was right and thanks for the help ! But I'm unable to crawl the whole site, just been able to crawl some 80 odd pages .. Anything that needs to be corrected ?  Here is my working version : (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('pages/')), follow=True, callback='parse_item'),)

Comment: hi! would you mind giving a help on this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630771/scrapy-linkextractor-duplicating

Comment: @Steven Almeroth   Hi Steven Can you help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717122/grabbed-data-from-a-given-url-and-put-it-into-a-file-using-scrapy    I tried with changes in rule but it didn't work for me .

Comment: dmoz.org does not have any links with "Items" in the href, so your rule is not finding any links and that is why your items.json file is empty.

Answer (score 2):

When parsing the `start_urls`, deeper urls can be parsed by the tag `href`. Then, deeper request can be yielded in the function `parse()`. [Here is a simple example](https://blog.siliconstraits.vn/building-web-crawler-scrapy/). The most important source code is shown below:

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from tutsplus.items import TutsplusItem
from scrapy.http    import Request
import re

class MySpider(Spider):
    name            = "tutsplus"
    allowed_domains = ["code.tutsplus.com"]
    start_urls      = ["http://code.tutsplus.com/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()

        # We stored already crawled links in this list
        crawledLinks = []

        # Pattern to check proper link
        # I only want to get tutorial posts
        linkPattern = re.compile("^\/tutorials\?page=\d+")

        for link in links:
        # If it is a proper link and is not checked yet, yield it to the Spider
            if linkPattern.match(link) and not link in crawledLinks:
                link = "http://code.tutsplus.com" + link
                crawledLinks.append(link)
                yield Request(link, self.parse)

        titles = response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "posts__post-title")]/h1/text()').extract()
        for title in titles:
            item = TutsplusItem()
            item["title"] = title
            yield item
```