# Scrapy does not crawl through data contained in start URLs

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to crawl an entire website using scrapy. As per scarpy's documentation

> start_urls - A list of URLs where the spider will begin to crawl from,
>   when no particular URLs are specified. So, the first pages downloaded
>   will be those listed here. The subsequent URLs will be generated
>   successively from data contained in the start URLs.

So according to this definition scrapy should spider through all the sub-urls on the pages mentioned under `start_urls` but it only crawls the url that I have specified. I did specify the rule as mentioned under [Scrapy - Crawl whole website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500281/scrapy-crawl-whole-website), but it didn't help. It only scrapes and outputs pages that I specify in start_urls.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
class AcdivocaFirstSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "example_sample"
    allowed_domains = ["example.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.org/site/id/home"]
    rules = rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1] #so eg it would name 'home'
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

This yields a single file with extracted HTML data for 'home' page. How do I get it to recursively crawl the entire website starting from the homepage?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 things to change:

- to use rules, make `AcdivocaFirstSpider` a subclass of `scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider`, not `scrapy.Spider`

> *The subsequent URLs will be generated successively from data contained in the start URLs.*

This phrase is misleading. `scrapy.Spider` by itself doesn't do anything special with those start URLs: it downloads them and passes the response's body to `parse()`. If the `parse()` callback is implemented to yield further requests, then yes, *subsequent URLs will be generated from data from those URLs*, but that's not automatic/automagical.

- when using `scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider`, you need to **NOT** override the built-in `parse()` method, that's where the rules are checked and requests for pages are generated. So you need to rename `parse` to `parse_item` (as referenced in your rule)

See [the warning in the docs on crawling rules.](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules)

Comment: That helped!! thank you so much, I ended up not overriding the default parse method, but defined one as a callback to be used!